# Are there any consequences to allow unsafe code in the project?

Tags: c#, unsafe

I have a piece of code that has to be run in unsafe context. I cannot compile it by default because the "Allow unsafe code" setting is unchecked in the project settings. Are there any bad consequences if I turn on this feature? Is it going to affect the rest of the code in the project, like some additional checks at runtime? I'd like to know why this setting exists in the first place, is it just to warn or prevent people from using the unsafe code unnecessarily?

My program doesn't really need the unsafe context, but there is one small tiny place where I need it, and I'm hesitating enabling it for the whole project, I don't want it to affect anything except the unsafe piece of code that is running in very specific cases.

Comment: Assemblies containing unsafe code won't load in a partially trusted environment. This used to be a little more relevant in the days where code access security was more important, but even so, there are still scenarios where needing full trust for an assembly is a potential issue. For your average desktop application it doesn't matter. The *main* problem with unsafe code is the code *itself*, of course; abandoning the guarantees of verified managed code is enough to justify having to toggle a flag. Sequestering it into a small assembly is an option.

Comment: @JeroenMostert sounds like a perfect answer to me, I think I'll just move the code to a separate assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post a comment by Jeroen Mostert, which seems to me a good answer:

> Assemblies containing unsafe code won't load in a partially trusted
>   environment. This used to be a little more relevant in the days where
>   code access security was more important, but even so, there are still
>   scenarios where needing full trust for an assembly is a potential
>   issue. For your average desktop application it doesn't matter. The
>   main problem with unsafe code is the code itself, of course;
>   abandoning the guarantees of verified managed code is enough to
>   justify having to toggle a flag. Sequestering it into a small assembly
>   is an option.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be consequences... but there is a way of reducing the impact of allow unsafe code by creating a separate assembly. In this way you just need to allow unsafe code for the new assembly instead of enabling it for the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using it for year because I have a function that copies memory via pointers... I've never noticed or had ill effects when running programs or services.